# Extract Data from a Multiple Web Pages into Excel - using VBA - Excel freezes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract the data from the following webpage into excel. The data from the below link spans to 7 pages (appr 3500 rows). I need this data into my excel work workbook.

www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?ex=N&sc_id=RI&pno=1&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2013-11-01

I have used the following macro to download the same....Unfortunately, the macro sreezes the excel application due to unknown reason. Please someone help.....

```
Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?sc_id=RI&pno={0}&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2013-11-01"
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 7

Sub test()
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String

    For page = 1 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page)
        Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.[a1])
        queryTableObject.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        queryTableObject.WebTables = "3"
        queryTableObject.Refresh
    Next page

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on my system and it works just fine.  What appears to be happening is:

1. The code executes quickly
2. The system reads the web based data source - the speed of this step depends on your internet connection speed

I get "ExternalData_1: Getting Data ..." in cell A1 while this is happening, and a message on the status bar switches between:

"Copying web data to sheet"
and
"Refreshing"

Overall time taken from execution to completion on my system with 2Mbps ADSL internet connection from South Africa is around 24 seconds.

I'm using Excel 2007